# Проверьте пожалуйста: перспектива - индикатив vs. сослагательное наклонение

Tags: наклонение

*Дом стоял на тихой улочке, хотя многочисленные глядевшие на него окна соседних домов и наводили на мысль о не меньшем количестве глаз, глядевших из-за занавесок.*

Помогите пожалуйста понять вот что: 
"*наводили на мысль*" - прошедшее время, так?
значит, действие на самом деле совершилось? 
хочу сказать, что автор тем самым выражает уверенность в том, что за гардинами на самом деле стоит кто-то и наблюдает, верно или нет?

правильно я думаю, что действие было бы гипотетическим, если бы оно было выражено так: 
*дом стоял на тихой улочке, хотя многочисленные глядевшие на него окна соседних домов **МОГЛИ БЫ НАВЕСТИ** на мысль о не меньшем количестве глаз, глядевших из-за занавесок.*
?

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Завершенность действия, выраженного действительным причастием прошедшего времени, зависит **от вида исходного глагола**: глядеть - несов. вид. Поэтому причастие обозначает действие в прошлом, развивающееся **одновременно** с действием глагола-сказуемого "наводили", это **незавершенное** действие (окна глядели и наводили на мысль).